# StandardSetController Pagination problem when use WHERE

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, database, standardsetcontroller

I try to make pagination for my table. When selectList change i take Id and want it in my Database Query, but if i add Where to soql the table isn`t displayed. My variable carId is null into if(setCon == null). How can a query be updated by selectList onchange?
I also tried using setCon.setFilterID (carId); but it didn’t help, maybe this is wrong way

```
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="appointments_list" collapsible="false">            
            <apex:selectList id="chooseCar" value="{! carId }" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{! carSelectOptionList }" />
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="appointmentsForm" action="{! PassCarToController }"/>
            </apex:selectList>        
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! appointments }" var="app">
                <apex:column headerValue="Action">
                    <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR('/' + app.Id)}" target="_blank">
                        View
                    </apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{! app.Car__c }"/>
                <apex:column value="{! app.SomeField__c }"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <apex:panelGrid columns="3">                    
                <apex:commandButton action="{! setCon.previous }" reRender="appointments_list" value="Previous" disabled="{! !setCon.hasPrevious }"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{! setCon.next }" reRender="appointments_list" value="Next" disabled="{! !setCon.hasNext }"/>                    
                <apex:outputText >{!(setCon.pageNumber * size)+1-size}-{!IF((setCon.pageNumber * size)>noOfRecords, noOfRecords,(setCon.pageNumber * size))} of {!noOfRecords}</apex:outputText>
            </apex:panelGrid>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Controller:

```
public String carId {get;set;}
public List<SelectOption> carSelectOptionList {get;set;}
public Appointment__c appointment {get;set;}
public Integer noOfRecords{get; set;}
public Integer size{get;set;}


public AppointmentsPageController (){ 
    carSelectOptionList = new List<SelectOption>();
    appointment = new Appointment__c();
    
    for (Car__c car : [SELECT Id, Name FROM Car__c]){ 
        carSelectOptionList.add(new SelectOption(car.Id, car.Name)); 
    }

public void PassCarToController() {
    Car__c car = [SELECT Id 
                     FROM Car__c 
                     WHERE Id = :carId Limit 1];
}
   
public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
    get {
        if(setCon == null) {
            size = 10;
            setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                [SELECT Car__c, SomeField 
                 FROM Appointment__c 
                 Where Car__c = :carId //-----------------------if comment this line all work
                 Order By Appointment_Date__c Desc Limit 10000]));
            setCon.setPageSize(size);
            
            noOfRecords = setCon.getResultSize();
        }
        return setCon;
    }
    set;
}

public List<Appointment__c> appointments {
    get{                
        return (List<Appointment__c>)setCon.getRecords();                
    } set; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PassCarToController method should reset the query:

```
public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon { get; set; }

public AppointmentsPageController (){ 
    carSelectOptionList = new List<SelectOption>();
    appointment = new Appointment__c();
    
    for (Car__c car : [SELECT Id, Name FROM Car__c]){ 
        carSelectOptionList.add(new SelectOption(car.Id, car.Name)); 
    }
    loadAppointmentDates();
}

public void PassCarToController() {
    loadAppointmentDates();
}
public void loadAppointmentDates() {
    size = 10;
    setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
        [SELECT Car__c, SomeField 
            FROM Appointment__c 
            Where Car__c = :carId
            Order By Appointment_Date__c Desc Limit 10000]));
    setCon.setPageSize(size);
    
    noOfRecords = setCon.getResultSize();
}
```

Using the "lazy load" technique that includes setting the standard set controller won't allow you to reset the controller when the value changes.

Additional changes may be necessary, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your method really helpful!